# Can't pass the dataTable data to modal (Mvc c#)

Tags: bootstrap-modal

Good Day mates.. what is wrong with my code when I call the modal, the data from data-table not shown into modal.

I am having issue on have passing the data from DataTable to myModal. And I Can't figure out where the problem is.

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#myTable').DataTable({
            "processing":true,
            "ajax": {
                "url": '@Url.Action("getEnrolles", "Register")',
                "type": "GET",
                "datatype": "json"
            },
            "columns": [
                { "data": "id_number", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "lrn", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "fname", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "mname", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "lname", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "status", "autoWidth": true },
                 {
                     "data": "id_number", "width": "50px", "render": function (data,type,row,meta) {
                         return '<button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"  data-toggle="modal" data-id="' + row.id_number + '" data-title="' + row.lrn + '" data-target="#myModal">...</button>';
                     }
                 }
            ]
        });
        $("#myModal").on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
            var triggerLink = $(e.relatedTarget);
            var id = triggerLink.data("id");
            var title = triggerLink.data("title");
            $("#modalID").text(id);
            $(this).find(".modal-body").html("<h5> title: " + title + "</h5>");
        });

    });
    }
</script>
```

```html
                        <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h3 id="modalID"></h3>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body"></div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Screen-shot of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKefm.png)

Comment: Good way of asking question. Congrats. But please include what is the exact issue you are facing while passing the data (error / exception / undefined or anything else).

Comment: it doesn't show error/exception/undefined, it just not show the data to modal. im using bootstrap 3

Comment: What do you mean by `it just not show the data to modal`. Also i tried to run your code snippet in the question. I guess it has a code error. Please check